# Как запретить элементу div изменять ширину себя?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Я использую следующий код:

```css
#input {
  transiction: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
#input:focus {
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
}
uans {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="uans"><input id="input"></div>
```

Проблема в том, что когда я фокусируюсь на поле ввода, внизу страницы появляется полоса прокрутки, а ширина div меняется. Как мне запретить ему изменяться в размерах?
max-width не подходит, я делаю адаптивную вёрстку.

Comment: Пример не воспроизводит проблему... а вообще, проверь `box-sizing` и маржины/паддинги в своих стилях. И если что, `div` по-умолчанию имеет `width: 100%;` - это подразумевает динамическое изменение его ширины по ширине родительского элемента (без указания значений ширины явно, "запретить" не получится).

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Вы можете это написать как ответ и я помечу это решением.

Comment: Тут лучше будет самоответ - т.к. я просто не знаю, что именно из перечисленного мной помогло :) Каждое из этих трех стилевых свойств может вызывать оверфлоу: как поодиночке, так и в комбинации (за исключением паддинга: который только вместе с бокссайзингом в значении "контент-бокс" может создать проблему, но не сам по себе).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне помогло изменение значения CSS-свойства [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).